# Cloudify blueprint upload import error

Tags: cloudify

we have an openstack deployment. We chose to deploy cloudify manager by image option. Now we are using the paid version of the manager image. When we tried to upload a openstack blueprint from the CLI:

> cfy blueprints upload -b vm -p cloudify-nodecellar-example-master/openstack-blueprint.yaml

we have the next output error on the cloudify manager:

> 20/12/2017 11:45:21 [INFO] [manager_rest.server] InvalidBlueprintError: Invalid blueprint - Failed to resolve the following urls: {u'file:///opt/manager/resources/spec/cloudify/4.3.dev1/types.yaml': "Import failed: Unable to open import url file:///opt/manager/resources/spec/cloudify/4.3.dev1/types.yaml; "}. In addition, failed to resolve the original import url - Import failed: Unable to open import url http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/4.3.dev1/types.yaml; HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.getcloudify.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /spec/cloudify/4.3.dev1/types.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
>     in: /opt/manager/resources/openstack-blueprint-b03206ec-1bde-4595-8cc0-93de5510f777/openstack-blueprint.yaml
>     in line: 7, column: 0
>     path: imports
>     value: ['http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/4.3.dev1/types.yaml', 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/openstack-plugin/2.0.1/plugin.yaml', 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/diamond-plugin/1.3.6/plugin.yaml', 'types/nodecellar.yaml', 'types/openstack-types.yaml']
>   20/12/2017 11:45:23 [INFO] [manager_rest.server] Authenticated user:

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are a few issues, which I will not go through here. The best way to get started is to follow the step-by-step instructions at [this link](https://github.com/cloudify-examples/cloudify-environment-setup).

If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask them here or in our [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloudify-users).